# rand() function that should not repeat

Tags: php

I have a code that present 4 pictures from a folder.
I use `rand()` function in order to present each time different picture for each one of these pictures, but sometimes, I receive the same picture in the same page.
what should I do in order to not receive the same picture twice?

Comment: Can you show us the code that you have so far?

Comment: Generally: **shuffle** the array instead of randomly picking one entry. Beyond that: what does "each time" mean? Separate page refreshes?

Comment: a pseudo-random generator such as rand() can pick two numbers in the same region since random really means each point in the space has equal probability of being picked.  So if you are using something like `$ipick = rand(0, 3)` then the chances of each is 1 in 4 so the likelihood of a repeat is fairly high.

Comment: Google "random (image) with no repeats".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd save all possible images in an array and [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) it, something like this:

```
$images = array('1.png','2.png','3.png','4.png');
shuffle($images);
foreach ($images as $image) {
    // do something with the image
}
```

Comment: Shuffling is no more random than `rand()` though. He could still get the pic twice in a row.

Comment: @Jay Not if they shuffle once and then iterate through the array and use each image in turn.

Comment: @JayBlanchard please provide evidence to that claim, as I know otherwise.

Comment: True @deceze - but no one had mentioned that yet :)

Comment: Here you go @NoyGabay - click run several times in a row and you will see that shuffle is just as random as `rand()` and doesn't prevent the OP's issue of showing the same image twice in a row. http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/jyzh-irqz

Comment: Why would you echo $image[0]..? What you want to do is [take the array and display it](http://ideone.com/nbOqiK). You have all the images there, randomly sorted, already. Anyway, updated my answer to make sure this (obvious?) part is covered, too.

Comment: Because it is unclear what the OP wants we are all guessing. Demonstrating that `shuffle()` and `rand()` aren't different - one is not more random than the other, as I stated above, is easy.

Comment: Thank you, I used the shuffle function to reorganize the array and choose each time different pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Do you start with all images in an array?

If so, I would personally use `shuffle($pictures);`

Then perhaps `array_chunk($pictures, 4)` to get groups of 4.

Answer (score 0):

I have make an function to do this. Use the code below

```
<?php

function GenRandom($min, $max, $quantity) {
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    return array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
}

foreach(GenRandom(1,4,4) as $test){
echo $test.".png<br>"; // generates unique id everytime
} 

?>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I have edited my answer please check it now

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate the array with all the pictures not randomized.
2. Random the whole array.
3. If needed save the randomized array in db (or somewhere else).
4. When showing a picture get the first value from the array to get random name.
5. Remove first value from the array.
6. Repeat points 4-5 on each request.
7. If array is empty go to point 1.